# Desktop PC takes time to turn on after pressing button

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

Lately, my desktop PC does not turn on the moment I press the power button. It takes a while (10 mins to half hour) to turn on. I can see the LED on the motherboard is on all the while, but it doesnt respond to anything else I have tried.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 5):

Your power supply probably needs to be replaced.  It's likely having trouble getting the power levels up to what they need to be to actually get the machine started until after enough time has passed.

If this is the case, then continued use in this manner may even damage your motherboard (which is normally more expensive than a new power supply) or other components in your computer (such as the hard drive).

Comment: Have same problem, using seasonic X series 760 watt. Twice. Both my original and replacement have this problem and now I'm confused. The thing is this happen in random occurance, but most of the time, powering on delay 4-10 seconds. Never as long as OP had. Other than that its powering on instantly, normal. Can I relate this with my house max power line suppy?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was caused by a dirty/rusted pin connector on mainboard.

Please find cables that connect the soft switch to the mainboard. Check the connector from that cable to main board, Unplug it, clean it (if possible) and plug it in back. Try doing it several times. And, please make sure the battery on mainboard is still in good condition.

Hope it helps.